# Kant's attitude to introspection

Tags: reference-request, kant, psychology

In "A History of Modern Psychology", Schultz & Schultz, 10th edition we read

> A century before Titchener’s work, the German philosopher
>   Immanuel Kant had written that any attempt at introspection necessarily altered the
>   conscious experience being studied because it introduced an observing variable into
>   the content of the conscious experience.

Can you please point me to the philosopher's exact work where he states the aforementioned?

Comment: See [Kant's View of the Mind](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mind/#3) for references to Kant, *The Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science* (1786).

Comment: Regarding introspection there are §§ 4 and 7 in his *Anthropology from a Pragmatic Point of View* where he adresses the doubling of the self in acts of introspection and reflection on the "I". I do not have an english copy of the text, therefore I cannote quote here, though.

Answer (score 2):

See:

- Immanuel Kant, [The Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=4CB7v1uSAaAC&pg=PA7) (1786), Eng.transl.by Michael Friedman (2004), *Preface* [471]:

> Yet the empirical doctrine of the soul must remain even further from
>   the rank of a properly so-called natural science than chemistry. In the
>   first place, because mathematics is not applicable to the phenomena of
>   inner sense and their laws [...].
>
> [In the second place,] however, the empirical doctrine of the
>   soul can also never approach chemistry even as a systematic art of analysis
>   or experimental doctrine, for in it the manifold of inner observation
>   can be separated only by mere division in thought, and cannot then be
>   held separate and recombined at will (but still less does another thinking
>   subject suffer himself to be experimented upon to suit our purpose),
>   *and even observation by itself already changes and displaces the state
>   of the observed object* [*emphasis added]. Therefore, the empirical doctrine of the soul can never become anything more than an historical doctrine of nature,
>   and, as such, a natural doctrine of inner sense which is as systematic as
>   possible, that is, a natural description of the soul, but never a science
>   of the soul, nor even, indeed, an experimental psychological doctrine.